# Read email body from a certain IMAP mailbox

Tags: c++builder, indy10

I'm trying to find a way to read only text from an email. Unfortunately, in `Memo1` there is still information about attachments as well as all information about the structure of the e-mail.

```
if ( IdIMAP1->UIDRetrieve( UID, IdMessage1 ) )
{
    IdMessage1->MessageParts->CountParts();
    if( IdMessage1->MessageParts->TextPartCount )
    {
        String b;

        IdIMAP1->UIDRetrieveText(UID, b);
        Memo1->Lines->Add( UTF8Decode(b) );
    }
}
```

I tried to use the `TIdText` function but the result `Str` is empty.

```
TStrings* Str = new TStringList;
TIdText( IdMessage1->MessageParts, Str );
```

`ContentType` of mesage is `multipart` but parts of mesage contains also `text/plain` type.

```
IdIMAP1->UIDRetrieveHeader(UID, IdMessage1);
IdMessage1->ContentType;
```

I tried to isolate the text part of the email but that didn't help either.

```
TIdMessagePart *Part;

for( int j = 0; j < IdMessage1->MessageParts->Count; ++j )
{
   Part = IdMessage1->MessageParts->Items[j];
   
  if( IsHeaderMediaType(Part->ContentType, "text/plain")
  {
    String b;
    IdIMAP1->UIDRetrieveText(UID, b);
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Is this ok using **stucture**?

```
TIdMessagePart *Part;
IdIMAP1->UIDRetrieveHeader(UID, IdMessage1);
IdIMAP1->UIDRetrieveStructure( UID, IdMessage1 );

for( int j = 0; j < IdMessage1->MessageParts->Count; ++j )
{
   Part = IdMessage1->MessageParts->Items[j];
    
   if( IsHeaderMediaType(Part->ContentType, "text/plain")
   {
     String b;
     IdIMAP1->UIDRetrieveText(UID, b);
   }
   else { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `TIdText( IdMessage1->MessageParts, Str );` does not do what you think.  It *adds* a new `TIdText` object to the `MessageParts`, initializing the object's `Body` text with the specified `TStrings` text.  Which is not what you want in this situation. Also, because Delphi-style objects (derived from `TObject`) must be created on the heap via `new`, so this statement should not even compile, producing an [E2459](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2459_Delphi_style_classes_must_be_constructed_using_operator_new_(C%2B%2B)) error.

Since you are downloading the email's *full* content via `UIDRetrieve()`, there is no reason to download individual text pieces via `UIDRetrieveText()` afterwards. You can just scan the `TIdMessage` contents you already have for the text portion you want. In your 2nd example, replace this:

```
String b;
IdIMAP1->UIDRetrieveText(UID, b);
```

with this:

```
String b = static_cast<TIdText*>(Part)->Body->Text;
```

Otherwise, you should take a different approach. IMAP is a very complex and flexible protocol. One of its features is it allows you to download an email's **structure** first (via `UIDRetrieveStructure()`), analyze those headers as needed to discover the `PartNumber` of the specific part(s) you want, and then you can download only those parts by themselves (via `UIDRetrievePart()`).

Comment: What about object are you talkikg about that must be created by `new`, TIdMessagePart?

Comment: @Jacek I was referring to your statement: "*I tried to use the `TIdText` function but the result `Str` is empty. `TStrings* Str = new TStringList; TIdText( IdMessage1->MessageParts, Str );`*" That code is trying to create a new object, but 1) such a creation requires `new`, and 2) such a creation is unnecessary in this situation anyway.